# Feed owners of the Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to feed Owners of the safe (to have always up-to-date data in my app). I cannot find a way to do it nor in SDK, API or any web3 function. Do you have any idea how to get it?

Comment: What is this concept of "safe"?

Comment: They are talking about the Gnosis Safe

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you would like to listen to owner changes of a specific Safe?

Comment: @Richard i'd like to feed the list of the Owners when my app starts. Cant find a way to do it.

Comment: What about https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#getowners ?